# Finding multiple least-cost-paths for a network of several points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cost-path

How can I find the least-cost-paths between a network of several points using QGIS or other easily available tools? That is, the easiest way to get from each point to every other point in the network, as opposed to just between one start and one end point.

The start and end points are polygons scattered unevenly across the map, and the intervening landscape is a patchwork of fields etc. for which the permeability score of each landscape feature is known - the least-cost-paths will need to choose any possible route through the fields, not follow roads or similar.

(I am using QGIS-2.14.1-Essen with GRASS).

Comment: Please ask only one question per question, for only one software platform (this is effectively four questions)

Comment: I reckoned that I'd have to explain most of the other questions for the individual questions to make sense!

Comment: Nothing overly complicated. Set any point as destination, compute back link raster for your cost surface, compute cost paths from the rest. Repeat 60 times to answer 2nd q, storing Eg 5 nearest distances or 30 times

Comment: Oops. 60 times to answer both

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/193046/115 but both could do with heavy revising to try and make what they are asking clearer.

Comment: Please can you reopen this question - I have made it much clearer, I think!

Comment: Also, FelixIP - how can I get it to run several times without sitting there clicking over and over again by hand?  Surely it will be more than 60 (at least (60 x 60) - 60 to be preise, plus a few more for where nearest patches) as each point can be the destination?

Answer (score 0):

This to me sounds similar  to a water flow analysis on a DEM. That basically calculates the lowest surrounding point and draws the path of water. Maybe this type of approach would be a helpful place to start?

https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/hydro.html